# MySQL - Select Info based on many tables

Tags: mysql, select, inner-join

I need to do the following:

**Select Usernames** from table **delivery** where **date>"2012-06-01 00:00:00"** then get **IP** from **Customers** order by IP and **remove duplicated usernames** (all based on the first usernames select).

```
select Username from delivery where date>"2012-06-01 00:00:00"
                        INNER JOIN Customers d
                        ON c.Username = d.Username order by IP asc;
```

It isn't working, any idea?

**EDIT:**

```
select Username from delivery c
    INNER JOIN Customers d
    ON c.Username = d.Username 
where date>"2012-06-01 00:00:00"
order by IP asc;
```

Comment: "It isn't working" Can you be more specific? Do you get an error message? What is the exact message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT d.Username, c.IP 
FROM delivery d INNER JOIN Customers c
    ON d.Username = c.Username 
   AND DATE(d.date) >= "2012-06-01"
ORDER BY c.IP
```

Comment: @Darkeden: did you try my query?

Comment: [Err] 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'GROUP BY d.Username' at line 6

Comment: The Error 1064 stills - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'GROUP BY d.Username' at line 6

Comment: @Darkeden: if you remove that part what happens? The query is executed?

Comment: I added DISTINCT right after SELECT and it's working. THANK YOU.

Answer (score 1):

1) The `WHERE` clause must come after the `JOIN ... ON ...` clause.

2) You reference a table `c`:

```
ON c.Username = d.Username
```

but you haven't defined what `c` is.

3) You want to remove duplicated usernames, but you didn't do that. You need to `SELECT DISTINCT Username` or `GROUP BY Username`.

4) To solve the problem of ambiguous column names you can use one of two approaches:

- Specify the table alias before the column name (separated by a dot).
- Use `USING` as the join condition, to avoid getting the `Username` column twice.

Here's an example of the second approach:

```
...
FROM delivery AS d
INNER JOIN Customers AS c USING (Username)
...
```

As you can see, it is much more concise and it means that you can reference `Username` elsewhere in the query without having to specify the table alias to disambiguate.

---

A completely different way to solve the problem is to use `EXISTS` instead of a `JOIN`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    Username, IP 
FROM customers
WHERE EXISTS
(
    SELECT *
    FROM delivery
    WHERE delivery.Username = customers.Username 
    AND delivery.date >= '2012-06-01'
)
ORDER BY IP
```

You may also be able to remove the `DISTINCT` when using this approach, assuming that there are no duplicates in your `customers` table.

Comment: Select Username.... c.Username = d.Username; - returns error [Err] 1052 - Column 'Username' in field list is ambiguous

Comment: it stills not working. "select distinct Username from delivery as c INNER JOIN Customers as d USING (Username) on c.Username = d.Username
where indate>"2012-06-01" order by IP asc;"

Comment: [Err] 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'on c.Username = d.Username where indate>"2012-06-01" order by IP asc;' at line 3

Comment: @Darkeden: The `USING` clause is **instead** of the `ON` clause. You shouldn't use both.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the alias on the first table:

```
select Username from delivery c 
INNER JOIN Customers d ON c.Username = d.Username
where c.date='2012-06-01 00:00:00'
order by IP asc;
```